# "navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result)" does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**Controller**

```
$scope.takePicture = function (options) {

  var options = {
     quality : 75,
     targetWidth: 200,
     targetHeight: 200,
     sourceType: 1
  };

  Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
     $scope.picture = imageData;;
  }, function(err) {
     console.log(err);
  });

};
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory('Camera', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }

});
```

**View:**

```
<button class = "button" ng-click = "takePicture()">Take Picture</button>
```

It gives me following error

> ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined
>   at Object.getPicture (services.js:7)

Comment: Are you calling `takePicture` after device is ready ?

Comment: And have you added the plugin to your project ?

Comment: @HardikVaghani i don't know what do you mean by device is ready. I am new in Ionic. Kindly explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @e666 yes plugin is added to project.

Comment: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("READY"); 
}` add this to your script. After it consoles "READY" then call function `takePicture`

Comment: Same issue boy. Does not work :(

Comment: On which device are you trying to test ? Also you can remove and readd the plugin ? `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngCordova that makes things easier http://ngcordova.com/ and you can use the camera code from there http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/ let me know if you have issue regarding that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.